# How can a big organization deal with the new cookie parameter "SameSite"

Tags: samesite

Our organization want to adapt to the new SameSite policies but it will create us a big impact, so as Google suggested to us we are asking here with the #samesite tag. Our situation is:

- We use more than one domain name and we have requests that are cross among those domains
- In Intranet (internal users) we have the great majority of the applications that do not use HTTPS protocol
- Cookies are widely used, for application purposes or security purposes (i.e Single Sign On)
- The standard browser is Chrome and we would like always to stay on the latest versions to benefit patching and optimizations comping from Google
- We don’t have a list of all the cookies that we are using and create such kind of list will generate a great effort

For all those reasons we wonder if our interpretation of the new policies is correct, in particular:

1. Should we convert all the Intranet application to HTTPS to continue to make cross domain requests? This would be a big impact to us
2. Will It be necessary to specify the SameSite parameter in all organization’s cookies if the new “lax” default won’t apply to our use cases (non idempotent requests between two different organization’s domains)? Having hundreds of applications and not having a consistent list of their cookies, this will be a very big impact to us
3. Should we introduce, in addition to the SameSite attribute, also the SameParty flag (we understood that in the future SameSite=”none” attribute might be dismissed)?
   Should we provide a JSON manifest as specified at this page https://github.com/privacycg/first-party-sets to Google?
   If this is the case, will all the navigations be considered SameParty or only the navigations from the owner to a secondary site; in other word could two secondary sites leverage the SameParty policy?
   Lastly, referring to the last paragraph of the quoted GitHub page, will the SameParty cookies be treated as First-Party cookies or as Third-Party cookies in the future?

Thank you!

Comment: *In Intranet (internal users) we have the great majority of the applications that do not use HTTPS* - doesn't this make your organization vulnerable to insider attacks, or just inadvertent disclosure of secret data?

Comment: I'm on this topic. Third party will be discontinued from 2022.
I'm trying figuring out how to share cookies in sameparty via chrome flags, but nothing works.
Do you have experienced a successfull test?